# Ignore if it's already fading

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p onclick="fade()">Click me</p>
<p id="myID">Text</p>

<script>
function fade() {
    $('#myID').fadeToggle('slow');  
}
</script>
```

If I spam "Click me", I mean if I click fast say ten times, "Text" continues to fade in and out until it has finished my ten clicks.

Is there anything I can do so that it ignores a click if it's already fading?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674255/jquery-click-event-ignore-double-clicks/3674293#3674293

Answer (score 3):

```
If ($("#myID").not(":animated"))
{
 $('#myID').fadeToggle('slow');  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use http://api.jquery.com/queue/ to find out whether there are any effects being performed on the element already. Something like (not tested):

```
if ($('#myID').queue().length == 0) $('#myID').fadeToggle('slow');
```

If you do want to stop the current effect and perform the toggle, use `.stop()` instead.

Comment: Don't use .stop with a fade effect. If the effect stops while the opacity is not 1, the next fade animation won't animate between 0 and 1 but between 0 and the opacity, where it stopped fading.

Comment: @dotweb: Not if you provide the proper arguments to `.stop()` ([second parameter](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)).

Answer (score 1):

source: [jQuery animation: Ignore double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674255/jquery-click-event-ignore-double-clicks/3674293#3674293)

```
<p onclick="fade()">Click me</p>
<p id="myID">Text</p>

<script>
function fade() {
    if( !$('#myID').is(':animated') ) {
    $('#myID').fadeToggle('slow');  
    }
}
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLwzx/)

Comment: I thought this one was the smoothest and closest to the OP's intent out of the different options.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches here, subtly different from one another.

---

#### Approach 1

```
function fade() {
    var $obj = $('#myID');
    if (!$obj.is(':animated')) {
        $obj.fadeToggle('slow');
    }
}
```

This is what you asked for. A new fade will only be queued if one isn't already going on.

The downside here is that we check for *any* animation (not just toggle fades), but you could expand this if really necessary (e.g. see Mike Thomsen's answer).

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Derjm/)

---

#### Approach 2

Instead of blocking *new* fades, you could cancel the *current* ones:

```
function fade() {
    $('#myID').stop(true, true).fadeToggle('slow');
}
```

The downside here is that the new animation starts immediately and this looks rather jarring.

The second parameter to `.stop` *must* be `true` (or you'll lose the element's original full opacity forever), and flipping the first one does not fix the downside of this approach.

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj9k3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function fade() {
    var that = this;
    if (!$(this).attr('fading')) {
        $(this).attr('fading', true);
        $('#myID').fadeToggle('slow', function() {
            $(that).removeAttr('fading');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but prefer `prop` or `data` I think.

Answer (score 0):

This works in my testing:

```
$('.fade').click(function() {
    $('#myID').stop(true, true).fadeToggle('slow');

});
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HtHpt/)

The idea to add paramaters to `stop()` came from this post: [jQuery fadeToggle if currently animated, ignore further input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722758/jquery-fadetoggle-if-currently-animated-ignore-further-input)

Comment: This stops the existing animations rather than ignoring further ones, and that is subtly different from what the OP's asking.